# resize type of ec2 with ansible

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

I want to resize a ec2 type from ansible.

This is my code:

```
- name: resize the instance
  ec2: 
    aws_access_key: "{{ aws_access_key_var }}"
    aws_secret_key: "{{ aws_secret_key_var }}"
    region: "{{ region }}"
    instance_ids:
      - "{{ instance_id }}"
    instance_type: "{\"Value\": \"t2.small\"}"
    wait: True
  register: ec2_result_file
```

But I get this error:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "image parameter is required for new instance"}
```

I try with command line all good

```
aws  ec2 modify-instance-attribute --region reg  --instance-id i-xx  --instance-type "{\"Value\": \"t2.small\"}
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

How to arrive at the solution:

1. Ansible tells you it wants to create "a new instance", but you already provided an existing instance ID.
2. Go to the docs for the [`ec2` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/modules/ec2_module.html) and check the argument in which you provided the ID of the current instance:

   > `instance_ids` list of instance ids, currently used for states: `absent`, `running`, `stopped`
3. Check what `state` you specified - you did not, so it's the default.
4. Check the same docs what is the default for `state` argument: it is `present`.

   `present` is not listed in the `instance_ids` description, so the `instance_ids` is completely ignored.

Ansible thinks you really wanted to create a new instance.

---

Solution:

Add `state: running` to the `ec2` module arguments.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo.

Comment: thanks again :) i tried with running, with stopped but nothing change only it start the machine or stopped the machine 
thanks again :) :P